# Excel VLOOKUP SUM with separate tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Trying to get a simple `VLOOKUP` to work but only getting first value.

**Sample Data**

**TABA**

```
     V
1
2    1
3    X
```

> X = `=SUM(VLOOKUP(V2,TABB!$K:$M,3,FALSE))`

**TABB**

```
     K  L      M
1    1  Hello  45
2    8  Hello  30   
3    1  Hello  20
4    6  Hello  60
5    1  Hello  90
6    3  Hello  10
7    1  Hello  80
8    1  Hello  75
```

**Current Output**

> =SUM(VLOOKUP(V2,TABB!$K:$M,3,FALSE))

Is returning 45 (the first value).

**Expected Output**

> =SUM(VLOOKUP(V2,TABB!$K:$M,3,FALSE))

I want it to return 310 (the `SUM` of values that match `1`).

Comment: You can use : `=SUMIF(TABB!K1:K8,A2,TABB!M1:M8)` or `=SUMPRODUCT((TABB!M1:M8)*(TABB!K1:K8=A2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlookup can only return the first value.

In your TABB Sheet. Create another column in Column N 
e.g in N1 with

```
=SUMIF($K$1:$K$8,$K1,$M$1:$M$8)
```

Drag the formula down

Then do

```
Vlookup(V2,TABB!$K:$N,4,FALSE)
```

If this works can you please vote up. :)
All the best

Comment: Why not just the sumifs in taba and skip the vlookup?